# JBOSS AS 7.1.1.Final Closing Leaked Connections?

Tags: java, jboss, database-connection, jboss7.x, connection-pooling

I have already done the following settings in standalone.xml as:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" pool-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
<cached-connection-manager debug="true" error="true"/>
```

Therefore, I am also getting the messages like "Closing a connection for you" as:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.jca.core.api.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-160) IJ000100: Closing a connection for you. Please close them yourself: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@5cdb81dc: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl.registerConnection(CachedConnectionManagerImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:495)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
```

Still, Sometimes my pool gets exhausted. It runs out of connections beyond 200 as defined. Why?

```
<min-pool-size>30</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
```

There is no way, that my application needs these much connections.
There is surely a connection leakage. And If it is, Why jboss is not closing it by it's own when I have enabled the setting as i said above:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" pool-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
<cached-connection-manager debug="true" error="true"/>
```

How to resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issue on our apps when we moved from Websphere to Jboss AS 7. I have listed detailed steps here. http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2013/10/troubleshooting-database-connection.html
     
The Key is to enable spy logging on the data source in addition to setting logging levels to DEBUG/TRACE ( used TRACE).
Here is how you enable Spy logging of your DB connection. 

<datasource
jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/TST_MYDB"
pool-name="TST_Datasource" enabled="true"
use-ccm="false" spy="true">

And 

<logger category="jboss.jdbc.spy">
  <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JBoss can not close all leaked connection.

You need to find leaked connection by checking logs after enabling JCA logging. I resolved connection leak by this way.

```
<logger category="org.jboss.jca">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

You will get entries like below in logs

`DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (MSC service thread 1-4) {JNDI_NAME}: getConnection(null, null) [1/100] -->` **It means taking connection from pool.**

`DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (MSC service thread 1-4) {JNDI_NAME}: returnConnection(607e334, false) [1/99]` --> **It means returning connection to pool**

You can check which query is not returning connetion to pool and check your application from where that query is being executed. Fix it.

Comment: How  to see the unclosed connections along with their Stacktrace, the listinUseConnections() method from the CachedConnectionManager MBean which can be invoked from the JMX-console. How to see this  in Jboss AS 7.1.1 ?

Comment: CachedConnectionManager doesn't have listinUseConnections() method in AS 7. 
Remove error=true from <cached-connection-manager debug="true" error="true"/>

Comment: [Patch](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1117)  you can find patch here to see listinUseConnection() method.

Comment: I am not very sure about compiled classes because I never used this. But You may get from later version of server.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more information to Neeraj's answer.

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (MSC service thread 1-4) {JNDI_NAME}: getConnection(null, null) [1/100]
```

The [1/100] at the end is [active connections/available connections] where:

```
active connections = createdCount - destroyedCount

available connections = maxPoolSize - inUseCount
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. If this information has value, it should be edited into the referenced answer.

Comment: Agreed but I am a new user and don't have enough reputation to do so.