# How to identify connection leaks

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I am using jboss with spring and hibernate. Transactions are managed using spring transaction management (@transactional). Now I am facing a few connection leaks intermittently and I am unable to identify where the problem comes from. It is failing with the following error:

> Unable to get managed connections for datasource.

Tried approaches like enabling `jca` debug logging in my `standalone.xml` but I don't see any errors there. Are there any other options to identify these? Can we find number of threads active for a particular transaction made or any other options to identify?

Comment: Did you checked hibernate session closed in your application?

Comment: You may get help from below.

[check this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884528/jboss-as-7-1-1-final-closing-leaked-connections/24950722#24950722